# Splash: How to achieve infinite loop in script?

Tags: python, lua, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash

I want to crawl a site which posts real-time data via *AJAX* and pass that data to an *alerting system*.

As I understand, I can only execute requests against splash, and these have to be finished after a certain time or the request will fail. Furthermore, I don't know how to return the data without exiting the *request/script*.

I would be grateful for a hint.

Comment: What is _infinite scraping_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always define a function and put the call to the function in a while loop.

```
def myFun():
    //Request language.
    return YourVar

while True:
    myFun()
```